# Xcode 5 build app for 10.8.5

Tags: xcode, osx-mountain-lion, osx-mavericks

The OX X App I built in Xcode 5 works great in OS X 10.9, but some of my coworkers are still using 10.8.5 and it won't open for them, Mountain Lion says 'This app requires 10.9'

How do I build the app to work for 10.8.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the General settings of the project, set "Deployment Target" to the earliest OS X version you want it to support.

[image: Screenshot]